# Flight info from a few days ago, trying to confirm if it was canceled?

Tags: american-airlines

I used Amierican Airlines for first time, flight coming home was April 29 from AUA to CHT, hour or so layover and CHT to BOS, we show up at airport in Aruba 3 hours prior to find out we are not on that plane we are on the next day April 30, and that there are no flights April 29 that have that route connection. They could not give a definite explanation, they said it was maybe my mix up with days, but I am 99.9% its not me, I wanted to know how to find out if I was bumped or flight was just canceled. If I go on website it will only show be the new flights as of today.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your itinerary / ticket? E-mail confirmation? That should be quite explicit regarding dates of the flights you booked.

Comment: Also, which flight was that supposed to be (flight number or departure time)? There are two flights AUA-CLT, one is daily (AA877, departing at 8:35 PM), the other one only runs on Saturdays and Sundays (AA875, departing at 6:31 PM).

Comment: We readily presume you meant Charlotte which is CLT. CHT is a speck of an airport on a small island belonging to New Zealand.

Comment: If you had been bumped, they would have told you this explicitly, given you compensation and so on.

Answer (score 7):

As per http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL877/history/20160429/2035Z/TNCA/KCLT AA877 was fine on the 29th. It was on schedule, left Queen Beatrix Airport gate 7 at 04:34PM AST (one minute early vs schedule) arrived to Charlotte gate B16 at 08:21PM EDT (still one minute early).

[image]

http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL875/history/20160430/1831Z/TNCA/KCHS AA875 is only weekends.